# Suggest a method and/or COTS application for providing Fly-Out Help Text on a Web Application that is database driven?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to propose a method for providing Help Text for the end users of a Web Application my company supports. Basically we want to have an area(s) on a Web Page where users can click or hover over and provide them with relevant Help so they don't have to refer back to the User Manual.

What we want to accomplish is to have all Help Text be populated to and read from a database so that it can be updated easily. We then need a way to identify which Web Pages and areas on a particular Web Page will need the corresponding and relevant Help text.

Has someone accomplished this through their own design and cares to share? or is there a commercial application out there that performs this very function?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might check out robohelp.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CtxtSensRoboHelp7WebHelp.aspx